# How do I check in TCL if a character from a string is alphanumeric or not?

Tags: regex, string, tcl

I need to check if characters from a string, taken individually, are alphanumeric, spaces or special characters. Unable to find a definitive way of doing this.

For example,

```
set str1 = "It is 5!"
```

so, my output should be:

```
I - Alphanumeric
t - Alphanumeric
" " - Space
i - Alphanumeric
s - Aplhanumeric
" " - Space
5 - Alphanumeric
! - Special Character
```

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10166 check this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good answer of @Donal.. Still if you want to use `regexp` as you mentioned in TAG.. You can probably do like this,

```
set var "Abc Def 8 9"
for {set i 0} {$i < [string length $var]} {incr i} {
    set char [string index $var $i]
    if {[regexp -all {[a-zA-Z0-9]} $char]} {
        puts "$char is Alphanumeric"
    } else {
        puts "$char is Special Character"
    }
}
```

It will solved your purpose of getting each character of string one by one... and check whether it's alphanumeric or special character..

Answer (score 4):

The `string is` command can be used to find out whether all the characters of a string are a member of a particular character class, can can be told to also report the index of the first character which is not a member of that class.

```
% string is alpha "abc"
1
```

```
% string is alpha -failindex ix "abc123"
0
% puts $ix
3
```

Relevant classes might be `alpha`, `digit`, `space` and `punct`. Also, `alnum` is the union of `alpha` and `digit`.

Comment: That's quite useful Donal! Thanks!